# Laravel Redis Queue - process job immediatelly, synchronously

Tags: laravel, redis, queue, laravel-queue

I know this is a bit contrary, but I need to dispatch a Job to be processed imediatelly, but following the normal Redis queue process.

Use case: I have a monitoring and job retrying system, which relies on jobs having `job_id` for tracking & retrying. This works great for queued jobs, however, there are certain cases where I want the job to be processed immediatelly and wait for the result (the same Job class sometimes needs to be queued and other times processed imediatelly). This is currently achieved by dispatching it to the `sync` queue, which, however, does not generate a job entry with the payload and the `job_id` so I cannot automatically retry it at a later date.

Is there a way to push a job through the Redis queue as normal, but instruct it to execute it immediatelly?

Comment: You could create another queue and dispatch the job to this queue instead of the original one in your specific case.